# Where are the Compiz-Settings stored

Tags: 16.04, unity, compiz, transparency

I'm trying to locate the item's stored in my opacity settings so i don't have to manually add this settings on each install i do.

I have tried so "locate compiz" and txt search my home for the settings without any luck. This are my settings for making windows transparent.

Any ideas?[image: Compiz, settings]

Comment: possible duplicate [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/246122/where-does-compiz-store-its-configuration-in-ubuntu-12-10)

Comment: Nope, its not in there ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After bit searching on net, it turn out compiz config settings are stored in:

```
$HOME/.config/compiz-1
$HOME/.gconf
```

Though I'm not sure, you might just want to backup/restore these file supposing it work. Worth a try.

Easiest alternative ways would be export your settings, with profile manager this can be done easily, so we'll save current settings to profile.

- Launch CompizConfig.
- Go to **Preferences** in left pane.
- On **Profile** section, press <kbd>Export</kbd> to export your compiz settings.
- Choose folder where to save your `.profile`.
- Press <kbd>Save</kbd> then.

To import, repeat previous steps with <kbd>Import</kbd> button, load your `.profile` files.

[image]

Comment: I've never noticed that :) None of this settings are in plain text so i could not find them anywhere...

Answer (score 0):

I can safely say that creating a new profile and saving your settings in a new profile doesn't work - You must have to export them and import them.

Nothing mentioned in the official 'documentation' about this broken feature, though.

Pathetically poor form, really, pushing broken/experimental features onto the uninformed and unaware.

Source: I just lost my Compiz configuration after testing if the Profile Management worked... It was a complete and utter failure.  Also, since the config files are in my home folder, the bundled recovery tool, TimeShift, didn't back them up!  A conflux of bad development decisions and non-existent, scant documentation, IMHO.

So, there's still plenty of glaring oversights (usually the pathetic threadbare documentation we have to make-do with - or visit a community forum - A 'social' replacement for proper, accurate, up-to-date, concise documentation) in most, if not all, Linux distros.